# SQL Server 2008 List rows with a duplicate value

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a SQL server (2008 R2) that stores metadata for files in a table. Each file has its own Row, and each file has an MD5 calculated and stored for it. I want to print a list of files where the MD5 value occurs more than once in the server, so I can go through and identify files that have been duplicated over time and decide which one to delete. I have a rather messy command full of several inner joins that I found works for my MySQL server from a few years ago, but modifying it to SQL Server hasn't worked for me yet. Any one know of any easier ways to do this? below is the modified MySQL command I was trying. Thanks

```
select [IGCSlidesDB].[dbo].[FilePath]
, [IGCSlidesDB].[dbo].[FileSize]
, [IGCSlidesDB].[dbo].[MD5] from [IGCSlidesDB].[dbo].[MD5Tool]
inner join ( select 
    [IGCSlidesDB].[dbo].[FilePath],
    [IGCSlidesDB].[dbo].[FileSize],
    [IGCSlidesDB].[dbo].[MD5] from [IGCSlidesDB].[dbo].[MD5Tool] group by [MD5] having count(*)>1) 
as t2 on ([IGCSlidesDB].[dbo].[MD5Tool].[MD5]=[t2].[MD5])
order by [IGCSlidesDB].[dbo].[MD5Tool].[FilePath];
```

Comment: Your 4-part naming looks odd to me. Format should be `ServerName.DatabaseName.SchemaName.ObjectName`.  Dbo is the default SchemaName, btw.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT  *, 
            COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY [MD5]) Total
    FROM [IGCSlidesDB].[dbo].[MD5Tool]
)
SELECT *
FROM CTE 
WHERE Total > 1
```

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding you correctly, for each MD5 in your MD5Tool table that is duplicated, you want to return those rows?

Give this a try:

```
SELECT M.FilePath, M.FileSize, M.MD5
FROM MD5Tool M
INNER JOIN ( 
    SELECT MD5 FROM MD5Tool GROUP BY MD5 HAVING COUNT(*)>1
) M2 ON M.MD5 = M2.MD5
ORDER BY M.FilePath;
```

And here is the [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/cf990/1).

Good luck.

Comment: This worked the same too, thanks! both this and the answer above returned the same rows.

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility:

```
select filepath, filesize, md5 
     from MD5Tool 
where md5 in 
     (select md5 from md5tool group by md5 having count(1) > 1)
order by filepath
```